# Teamcity cli step fails in continuous build while works manually

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, teamcity

I have ported my project build from buildbot to teamcity and it now fails on a command line step where I call a shell script that:
1) launches the *macdeployqt* qt utility to codesign the built app and then
2) tries to notarize the app.

I always get a **sigsegv** during the launch of *macdeployqt*

Obviously launching the script manually on the same machine and folder works as expected.

Comment: Check the user account permission which is running under Teamcity agent,

Comment: @NirajGajjar the build machine is the same where the buildbot agent is run and the user is the same too, so the environment should be equal when running buildbot or teamcity. Do you have any specific checks in mind?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on my side, a JetBrains support staff stated that command-line runner is just calling the script as it is and not modifying any environment. It turned out that the script was failing because there was a double / in a path.